# Converting PCM 16 bit audio to PCM 8 bit

Tags: java, android, audio, audio-recording

I want to implement in my android recording app the possibility to record using both PCM 16 bit and PCM 8 bit. I have a problem `converting a byte[] PCM 16 bit to 8 bit`, I tried different approaches, `but the size of the recording remained the same (for PCM 8 bit the size should be half of the PCm 16 bit)`. Here are those 2 approaches:

first one:

```
        if(encoding == AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT){
            int i,j;
            int tempint;
            int len = data.length;
            for (i=1, j=0; i<len; i+=2, j++){
               tempint = ((int) data[i]) ^ 0x00000080;
               data[j] = (byte) tempint;                    
            }
        }
```

second one:

```
        if(encoding == AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT){
            int len = data.length;
            for (int i=0, i<len; i++){
                data[i] = (byte)(data[i] >> 8);
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you use the same array to store the converted data then it has of course the same size. You must write it to a new array

Comment: You are right, was a mistake from me(a bit tired right now). Please post your answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the same array to store the converted data then it has of course the same size. You must write it to a new array.